# How do I make a vertical line with text in the middle surrounded by two divs? - html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a tile calculator for my website and I'm having trouble implementing the last thing before it's ready.

[image: Current Design]

The image above shows the current state of the UI. What I need help with is to centre the "OR" vertically and add two vertical lines above and below it.

Below is the html for the calculator (excluding the javascript) and  the css for the most of the calculator (let me know if you want all of it). The "OR" is in a div surrounded by another two divs.

```css
.holderCalc {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  border: solid 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.divCalc1 {}

.divCalc2 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.divLine1 {
  width: 80.7%;
}

.divLine2 {
  width: 90.8%;
}

.lxbBox {
  width: 50%;
}

.area10Calc {
  width: 50%;
}

.inputCalc {
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: futura-pt;
  padding: 2px;
```

```html
<div class="holderCalc">
  <br>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="lxbBox">
      <select class="inputCalc" id="ddm" onchange="areaUpdated()">
        <option value="mm">MILLIMETRES</option>
        <option value="cm">CENTIMETRES</option>
        <option value="inch">INCHES</option>
        <option value="m">METRES</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input id="len" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="LENGTH" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()"><br>
      <p class="divCalc2">X</p>
      <input id="wid" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="WIDTH" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()">
    </div>
    <div class="divCalc1">OR</div>
    <div class="area10Calc">
      <input id="area" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="AREA (M²)" autocomplete="off" onclick="areaUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()"><br><br><br>
      <hr class="divLine1" size="2px" color="black">
      <br>
      <input id="addWaste" type="checkbox">
      <label class="text" for="addWaste">ADD 10% FOR CUTS AND WASTES</label><br><br>
      <button onclick="calculate()" class="calculateButton">CALCULATE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divLine2" size="2px" color="black">
  <p class="text" id="output">TO COVER 0.00M², YOU NEED 0 TILES</p>
</div>
```

If you need anything else, please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: `align-items: center` on the wrapper for the first part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `align-items: center` on the wrapper and two pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` which you set to `width: 0` and its `border` to 1px, so that it becomes 2px (border-left + border-right). The wrapper needs `position: relative` for that.

The pseudo elements are positioned absolutely and can be alligned to the center by setting its `left` property to `50%`. "Below" and "above" are controlled by `bottom: 0` and `top: 0`.

```css
.holderCalc {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  border: solid 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.divCalc1 {}

.divCalc1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 40%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.divCalc1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 40%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.divCalc2 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.divLine1 {
  width: 80.7%;
}

.divLine2 {
  width: 90.8%;
}

.lxbBox {
  width: 50%;
}

.area10Calc {
  width: 50%;
}

.inputCalc {
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: futura-pt;
  padding: 2px;
```

```html
<div class="holderCalc">
  <br>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="lxbBox">
      <select class="inputCalc" id="ddm" onchange="areaUpdated()">
        <option value="mm">MILLIMETRES</option>
        <option value="cm">CENTIMETRES</option>
        <option value="inch">INCHES</option>
        <option value="m">METRES</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input id="len" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="LENGTH" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()"><br>
      <p class="divCalc2">X</p>
      <input id="wid" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="WIDTH" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()">
    </div>
    <div class="divCalc1">OR</div>
    <div class="area10Calc">
      <input id="area" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="AREA (M²)" autocomplete="off" onclick="areaUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()"><br><br><br>
      <hr class="divLine1" size="2px" color="black">
      <br>
      <input id="addWaste" type="checkbox">
      <label class="text" for="addWaste">ADD 10% FOR CUTS AND WASTES</label><br><br>
      <button onclick="calculate()" class="calculateButton">CALCULATE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divLine2" size="2px" color="black">
  <p class="text" id="output">TO COVER 0.00M², YOU NEED 0 TILES</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, update the html for `divCalc1`:

```html
<div class="divCalc1"><span>OR</span></div>
```

Then, update the css for `wrapper` and `divCalc1`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.divCalc1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.divCalc1::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.divCalc1 span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
  .holderCalc {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  border: solid 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.divCalc1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.divCalc1::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.divCalc1 span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 2;
}

.divCalc2 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.divLine1 {
  width: 80.7%;
}

.divLine2 {
  width: 90.8%;
}

.lxbBox {
  width: 50%;
}

.area10Calc {
  width: 50%;
}

.inputCalc {
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: futura-pt;
  padding: 2px;
```

```html
<div class="holderCalc">
  <br>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="lxbBox">
      <select class="inputCalc" id="ddm" onchange="areaUpdated()">
        <option value="mm">MILLIMETRES</option>
        <option value="cm">CENTIMETRES</option>
        <option value="inch">INCHES</option>
        <option value="m">METRES</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input id="len" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="LENGTH" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()"><br>
      <p class="divCalc2">X</p>
      <input id="wid" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="WIDTH" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()">
    </div>
    <div class="divCalc1"><span>OR</span></div>
    <div class="area10Calc">
      <input id="area" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="AREA (M²)" autocomplete="off" onclick="areaUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()"><br><br><br>
      <hr class="divLine1" size="2px" color="black">
      <br>
      <input id="addWaste" type="checkbox">
      <label class="text" for="addWaste">ADD 10% FOR CUTS AND WASTES</label><br><br>
      <button onclick="calculate()" class="calculateButton">CALCULATE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divLine2" size="2px" color="black">
  <p class="text" id="output">TO COVER 0.00M², YOU NEED 0 TILES</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - not centered vertically and no vertical line...

Comment: Can you create a JSFilddle or Codepen example?

Comment: I added a stack snippet to your answer with your changes. Click on "Run code snippet" to see the result...

Comment: I have updated the `css`. It should work now

Comment: Yes, now it works. I updated the stack snippet in your answer too...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-wave-puzsn?file=/index.html

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

I've used `display:table` and `verticle-align : middle` for achieving this result.
Display table is very helpful specially when you need equal height `div`s

Comment: Updated with Verticle line. https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-wave-puzsn?file=/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you:-

CSS change

```
.divCalc1{
  border-top: solid 2px black;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Nope. It doesn't allign vertically and the borders should also be vertically.